# Setar <option> ao marcar/desmarcar checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Preciso resetar um `select` através de uma `checkbox`.
O problema está no momento em que tento acessar a `option` com a jQuery.

HTML

```
<select id="selSub">
 <option value="0" >Selecione</option>
 <option value="1" >1</option>
 <option value="2" >2</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var checkBox = $("#c1").prop('checked');
  $('#divSubIn').hide();
  $("#c1").click(function(){
    if($('#c1').is(":checked")) {
      //IF CHECKED      
      $('#label1').text("insira uma nova >>");
      $('#divSubSel').hide();
      $('#divSubIn').show();
      $('#selSub').material_select('selectedIndex', 0);
    }else{
      //IF UNCHECKED
      $('#label1').text("Inserir subcategoria nova");
      $('#divSubSel').show();
      $('#divSubIn').hide();      
    }
  });  
});
```

Dentro do `// IF CHECKED` o quarto elemento `$('#selSub').material_select('selectedIndex', 0);` deveria voltar o select ao normal = `<option value="0" >Selecione</option>`.

Comment: Se você quer apenas resetar o select. Basta trocar: "$('#selSub').material_select('selectedIndex', 0);" por: "$('#selSub').val('0');"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só fazer assim

```
$('#selSub').val('0');
```

Fontes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Paulo, não funcionou, o select nao volta ao Selecione apos clicar na checkbox, o materialize usa um script para iniciar o select, o problema deve estar ai...

Comment: O que é MATERIALIZE?

Comment: Um framework, desenvolvido pelo Google, baseado no material design:
http://materializecss.com/